# Why am i seeing the following error: "737: psycopg.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "users" does not exist"

Tags: python, sql, visual-studio-code

the users table that i am using has been run via sql in another database. I'm not sure that my python query is running from the correct database - how do i ensure that it runs from a given database rather than the default one?

For context i have run the following so it should be accessible via the chitter_app database:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 chitter_app < seeds/chitter_table.sql

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users cascade;
CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    name_of_user text,
    email_address text,
    username text,
    user_password text,
    logged_in_status Boolean
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS peeps;
CREATE TABLE peeps (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    peep text,
    peep_dateime TIMESTAMP,
    user_id int,
    CONSTRAINT fk_users FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO users (name_of_user, email_address, username, user_password) VALUES ('name', 'name@hotmail.co.uk', 'nameuser', 'password123');
```

i have written some separate python code elsewhere, which extracts data from the users table:

```
rows = self._connection.execute('SELECT * FROM users')

def all(self):
        rows = self._connection.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
        print(rows)
        all_rows = []

^ this is the part that cannot recognise the table 'users'
```

i have presumed that issue is that the code is not connecting to the correct database... i have tried creating new databases, recreating the table, running the scripts multiple times, reinstalling pipenv dependencies etc

Comment: could we see how you are establishing the connection?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are creating a table and selecting data from that table in different schemas. Python by default uses the **Public** schema